# Why is Wget option --reject not working with redirections?

Tags: wget

I am trying to download recursively a website by filtering out some zip files with this (simplified) command :

`wget <other_args...> --reject 'zip' https://www.domain.tld`

This is not working! Wget sees that the URL pointing to the file is a 302 redirect going to 'https://www.domain.tld/html/path/to/file.zip' and download the zip file without rejecting the url !

This is the request / response pipe wget is following :

- Wget Request  → `https://www.domain.tld/html/path/to/file.html`
  (--reject 'zip' works here)
- Server Response → `302 redirect`
- Wget Request  → `https://www.domain.tld/html/path/to/file.zip`
  (--reject 'zip' does not work here)

This is also not working with `--reject-regex '\.zip$`' as I have also tried!

I am stuck here, there is no current option to filter out urls by mime type (application/zip) with the latest version I use (1.21.2).

A workaround would have been to use the latest wget 2.0, which offers mime type filtering, but I'm using wget to generate warc files which is not supported yet in the current 2.0 version (wget/libwarc is available but not integrated).

Maybe am I doing something wrong, do you have any hints or a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: The only explanation I have found so far is that a redirect url is not filtered using --reject-regex among other options as says this post (2016) : https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-wget/2016-10/msg00029.html

"Note that if an HTTP request receives a redirection response, the redirect URL is subjected to the same tests as any recursively-fetched URL, with the exception that the --include-directories, --exclude-directories, --accept-regex, and --reject-regex tests are not applied. " The end of the post explains a problem in the order redirected urls are processed by wget, was this fixed?